# Filter the array of objects with same id and sort the sequence and take the highest one in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this.

```
var vg = [
  { id: "99", seq: "8" }, 
  { id: "99", seq: "2" }, 
  { id: "98", seq: "8" }, 
  { id: "98", seq: "3" }, 
  { id: "97", seq: "8" }, 
  { id: "97", seq: "7" }
]
```

So now I want to get unique `id`s with highest sequence value. Here is what I've tried:

```
if (vg && vg.length > 0) {
  vg = vg.sort(function ( a, b ) { 
    return b.sequence - a.sequence; 
  });
  arr.push(vg[0]);
}
```

This is my expected out:

```
[
  { id: "99", seq: "8" }, 
  { id: "98", seq: "8" }, 
  { id: "97", seq: "8" } 
]
```

Comment: I think your solution is okay, you just need to sort with sequence as number not string. `return parseInt(b.sequence) - parseInt(a.sequence)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can firstly `.sort()` in descending order and then get unique values from your array by using `.filter()` on your array by only keeping the elements where the found first index of an element with a given `id` is equal to the current index like so:

```js
const vg = [{"id":"99","seq":"8"}, {"id":"99","seq":"2"}, {"id":"98","seq":"8"}, {"id":"98","seq":"3"}, {"id":"97","seq":"8"}, {"id":"97","seq":"7"}];

const unq = vg
             .sort(({seq: a}, {seq: b}) => b-a)
             .filter(({id}, i) => i === vg.findIndex(({id: _id}) => id === _id));
console.log(unq);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```js
var vg = [{"id":"99","seq":"8"}, {"id":"99","seq":"2"}, {"id":"98","seq":"8"}, {"id":"98","seq":"3"}, {"id":"97","seq":"8"}, {"id":"97","seq":"7"}]

function getUniArr(arr){
  var opt=[];
  var indexArr=[];
  arr.map((item)=>{
     let key=indexArr.indexOf(item.id);
     if(key==-1){
      indexArr.push(item.id);
      opt.push(item);
     }else if(opt[key].seq<item.seq){
       opt[key]=item;
     } 
  })
  return opt;
}

console.log(getUniArr(vg));
```

Answer (score 0):

may be this one ?

```js
const vg = 
    [ { id: "99", seq: "8" } 
    , { id: "99", seq: "2" } 
    , { id: "98", seq: "8" } 
    , { id: "98", seq: "3" } 
    , { id: "97", seq: "8" } 
    , { id: "97", seq: "7" } 
    ] 

const uniq = vg.reduce((ac,el)=>
  {
  let same = ac.find(a=>a.id===el.id)
  if (same) { if (same.seq < el.seq) same.seq = el.seq } 
  else      { ac.push(el) }
  return ac
  }
  ,[])

// result
uniq.forEach((el,i)=>console.log(`[${i}] -> ${JSON.stringify(el)}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

other method ( remove "bad" elements and didn't create a new array)

```js
const vg = 
    [ { id: "99", seq: "8" } 
    , { id: "99", seq: "2" } 
    , { id: "98", seq: "8" } 
    , { id: "98", seq: "3" } 
    , { id: "97", seq: "8" } 
    , { id: "97", seq: "7" } 
    ] 
    
for(let i=vg.length;i--;)
  {
  let bigger = vg.find(v=>v.id===vg[i].id && v.seq > vg[i].seq )  
  if (bigger) vg.splice(i,1)
  }
  
// proof
vg.forEach((el,i)=>console.log(`[${i}] -> ${JSON.stringify(el)}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to get the unique `id` with highest `seq` in an object accumulator and then get all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const values = [ { id: "99", seq: "8" } , { id: "99", seq: "2" } , { id: "98", seq: "8" } , { id: "98", seq: "3" } , { id: "97", seq: "8" } , { id: "97", seq: "7" } ],
      result = Object.values(values.reduce((r, {id, seq}) => {
        r[id] = r[id] || {id, seq};
        if(r[id].seq < seq) r[id] = {seq, id};
        return r;
      },{})).reverse();
console.log(result);
```